# After adding bootstrap there is white line between my divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, division

## This is my HTML code.

there was no problem with my project until i added bootstrap.

it seems the details is nt enough so iam writing this pls if u know anything pls correct my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="main.js" defer></script>
        <title>test home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="hero">
            <video autoplay loop muted plays-inline class="back-video">
                <source src="Wolf.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <nav>
                <img src="Wild logo2.png" class="logo">
                <div class="menu-btn">
                    <div class="menu-btn_lines"></div>
                </div>
                <ul class="menu-items">
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#mission-id">MISSIONS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">COURSE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <li><a type="submit" class="cta" href="#"><button>LogIn</button></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav> 
           <div class="content">
            <h1>WILDPRO</h1>
            <a href="#">READ</a>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="banner">
           <h2>
            Photography is life.
           </h2>
           <br><br><br>
           <p>Wildlife photography is one of the most exciting photographic genres out there. But it can be difficult to get started as a wildlife photographer because of all the gear, technical know-how, and additional knowledge required.In the early days of photography, it was difficult to get a photograph of wildlife due to slow lenses and the low sensitivity of photographic media. Earlier photos of animals were often captive animals. These included photos of lion cubs taken at the Bristol zoo in 1854 and in 1864, photos of the last Quagga by Frank Hayes. Wildlife photography gained more traction when faster photography emulsions and quicker shutters came in the 1880s. Developments like these lead to photos such as the ones taken by German Ottomar Anschutz in 1884, the first shots of wild birds in action. Members of the Delaware Valley Ornithological Club (DVOC) captured early photographs of nesting songbirds in the Philadelphia area in 1897.In July 1906, National Geographic published its first wildlife photos.The photos were taken by George Shiras III, a U.S. Representative from Pennsylvania. Some of his photos were taken with the first wire-tripped camera traps.</p>
           <div class="custom-shape-divider-bottom-1676808801">
            <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <path d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
            </svg>
        </div> 
        </div>  
        <div id="mission-id" class="mission">
            <h2>
                Missions.
            </h2>
            <br>
            <p>
                The website intends on to focus on many rescue missions,for a bright future for the wild animals and <span>SAVE</span> many animals from their existition.
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## This is my CSS code

the css code seem to have some position problem or something

### this is a screenshot of my project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x982.png)

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;500&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
li, a, button{
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.hero{
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),rgb(0, 150, 17));
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 5%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
input{
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 60px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
}
::placeholder{
    color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.767);
}
nav{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px 8%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
nav .logo{
 margin-right:auto;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
nav ul li a{
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #0ea900;
}
.menu-btn {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 3;
}
.menu-btn_lines,
.menu-btn_lines::before,
.menu-btn_lines::after{
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 0.1rem;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-btn_lines::before,
.menu-btn_lines::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
}
.menu-btn_lines::before{
    transform: translateY(-0.5rem);
}
.menu-btn_lines::after{
    transform: translateY(0.5rem)
}
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn_lines{
    transform: translateX(2rem);
    background-color: transparent;
}
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn_lines::before{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-1.5rem,1.5rem);
}
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn_lines::after{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-1.5rem,-1.5rem);
}
button{
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: rgb(54, 169, 0);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
button:hover{
    background-color: rgba(6, 182, 0, 0.8);
}
.content{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

.content h1{
    font-size: 160px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.content h1:hover{
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #fff;
    color: transparent;
    cursor: default;
}
.content a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 14px 70px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.back-video{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -2;
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9){
    .back-video{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9){
    .back-video{
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
.banner{
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color:rgb(0, 150, 17);
    width: 100;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding:0 5%;
    align-items: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
.banner h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.banner p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 2%; 
    padding-bottom: 8%;
}
.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1676808801 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1676808801 svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: calc(116% + 1.3px);
    height: 100px;
}

.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1676808801 .shape-fill {
    fill: #0b8500;
}
.mission{
    margin-top: 0;
    float: top;
    background-color: #0b8500;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding:0 5%;
    align-items: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
.mission h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.mission p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 2%; 
    padding-bottom: 8%;
}
.mission span{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 900;
    background-image: linear-gradient(98deg,red,blue);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .custom-shape-divider svg {
        width: calc(250% + 1.3px);
        height: 150px;
    }
    .menu-btn{
        display: flex;
    }
    .menu-items {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        transform: translateX(100vw);
        background-color: #0ea900;
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .menu-items.open {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    .menu-items li {
        width: 50vw;
        height: 10%;
        margin-top: 10%;
    }
    .menu-items li a {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 2vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
    }
    .banner h2{
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .banner p{
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        padding-bottom: 20%;
    }
    .content h1{
        font-size: 80px;
    }
    nav .logo{
        width: 20%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding class="m-0" to the p tag inside div.banner like this:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;500&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
li, a, button{
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.hero{
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),rgb(0, 150, 17));
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 5%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
input{
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 60px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
}
::placeholder{
    color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.767);
}
nav{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px 8%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
nav .logo{
 margin-right:auto;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
nav ul li a{
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #0ea900;
}
.menu-btn {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 3;
}
.menu-btn_lines,
.menu-btn_lines::before,
.menu-btn_lines::after{
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 0.1rem;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-btn_lines::before,
.menu-btn_lines::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
}
.menu-btn_lines::before{
    transform: translateY(-0.5rem);
}
.menu-btn_lines::after{
    transform: translateY(0.5rem)
}
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn_lines{
    transform: translateX(2rem);
    background-color: transparent;
}
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn_lines::before{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-1.5rem,1.5rem);
}
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn_lines::after{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-1.5rem,-1.5rem);
}
button{
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: rgb(54, 169, 0);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
button:hover{
    background-color: rgba(6, 182, 0, 0.8);
}
.content{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

.content h1{
    font-size: 160px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.content h1:hover{
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #fff;
    color: transparent;
    cursor: default;
}
.content a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 14px 70px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.back-video{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -2;
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9){
    .back-video{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9){
    .back-video{
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
.banner{
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color:rgb(0, 150, 17);
    width: 100;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding:0 5%;
    align-items: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
.banner h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.banner p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 2%; 
    padding-bottom: 8%;
}
.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1676808801 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1676808801 svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: calc(116% + 1.3px);
    height: 100px;
}

.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1676808801 .shape-fill {
    fill: #0b8500;
}
.mission{
    margin-top: 0;
    float: top;
    background-color: #0b8500;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding:0 5%;
    align-items: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
.mission h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.mission p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 2%; 
    padding-bottom: 8%;
}
.mission span{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 900;
    background-image: linear-gradient(98deg,red,blue);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .custom-shape-divider svg {
        width: calc(250% + 1.3px);
        height: 150px;
    }
    .menu-btn{
        display: flex;
    }
    .menu-items {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        transform: translateX(100vw);
        background-color: #0ea900;
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .menu-items.open {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    .menu-items li {
        width: 50vw;
        height: 10%;
        margin-top: 10%;
    }
    .menu-items li a {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 2vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
    }
    .banner h2{
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .banner p{
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        padding-bottom: 20%;
    }
    .content h1{
        font-size: 80px;
    }
    nav .logo{
        width: 20%;
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    <title>test home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hero">
        <video autoplay loop muted plays-inline class="back-video">
            <source src="Wolf.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <nav>
            <img src="Wild logo2.png" class="logo">
            <div class="menu-btn">
                <div class="menu-btn_lines"></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="menu-items">
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#mission-id">MISSIONS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">COURSE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a type="submit" class="cta" href="#"><button>LogIn</button></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav> 
       <div class="content">
        <h1>WILDPRO</h1>
        <a href="#">READ</a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
       <h2>
        Photography is life.
       </h2>
       <br><br><br>
       <p class="m-0">Wildlife photography is one of the most exciting photographic genres out there. But it can be difficult to get started as a wildlife photographer because of all the gear, technical know-how, and additional knowledge required.In the early days of photography, it was difficult to get a photograph of wildlife due to slow lenses and the low sensitivity of photographic media. Earlier photos of animals were often captive animals. These included photos of lion cubs taken at the Bristol zoo in 1854 and in 1864, photos of the last Quagga by Frank Hayes. Wildlife photography gained more traction when faster photography emulsions and quicker shutters came in the 1880s. Developments like these lead to photos such as the ones taken by German Ottomar Anschutz in 1884, the first shots of wild birds in action. Members of the Delaware Valley Ornithological Club (DVOC) captured early photographs of nesting songbirds in the Philadelphia area in 1897.In July 1906, National Geographic published its first wildlife photos.The photos were taken by George Shiras III, a U.S. Representative from Pennsylvania. Some of his photos were taken with the first wire-tripped camera traps.</p>
       <div class="custom-shape-divider-bottom-1676808801">
        <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <path d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
        </svg>
    </div> 
    </div>  
    <div id="mission-id" class="mission">
        <h2>
            Missions.
        </h2>
        <br>
        <p>
            The website intends on to focus on many rescue missions,for a bright future for the wild animals and <span>SAVE</span> many animals from their existition.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```